# Why can't I use my SO login credentials on Meta?

Tags: discussion

In my view, meta.stackoverflow.com is a forum related to stackoverflow.com. That is, this is a portal/site dedicated to comments/improvements related to Stack Overflow. If this is so, why do I need to create a separate login/account for meta.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Meta supports *three* sites (Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User), each with separate user profiles. So it's not as easy as a one-to-one mapping of accounts.

Comment: Your view is wrong... Meta is about waffles and ponies!

Comment: and hand drawn circles!

Answer (score 8):

StackOverflow sites, including meta, use openID.  The same OpenID credentials you used to log in to StackOverflow.com should work just fine here at meta.stackoverflow.com.

If you use the same OpenID, you can associate your accounts in your user profile page.

Comment: you are in no way answering the question.. why do you need another account not how do i get that other account easily and have them associated.

Answer (score -2):

Because the site/sites is/are messed up..

It makes little enough sense that a question one posts can get migrated to another site (e.g. serverfault) where one needs another log in to access that question. If the question can be migrated why does that account not work!

Like you said there is no reason why a forum on SO should have a separate log in.. maybe it was easier to code ;-)

If meta is for stackexchange not stackoverflow they should consider changing the URL to meta.stackexchange.com (which redirects here anyways).

Personally I think that the separate log ins is one of the worst features of SO..

I actually find it insulting that there is a notification system for stackexchange but not an authentication system for it! If you can give me messages from all accounts together then here's a crazy idea... HAVE ONE ACCOUNT! lol

Que answer deletion in 5...4...3...2...1...

Comment: Remember: We're not a forum. We don't work like a forum. We don't have one login like a forum. The "meta.stackexchange" thing has been brough up (many, *many*) times, read [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52026/why-do-we-ask-area-51-questions-here-meta-stackoverflow-rather-than-on-meta-sta/52035#52035) for more info. Also, your answer won't be deleted, just probably heavily downvoted. But, tell me, how would you do it? For each member, create them an account on each and every site, even if they don't visit it? And what about the sites that haven't even been made yet?

Comment: nope just a stack exchange account, and I you are right about the forum thing, sorry.