# Why do we ask Area 51 questions here (meta.stackoverflow) rather than on meta.stackexchange?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, meta, area-51

Since [Area 51 has been announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52005/stack-exchange-area-51-sneak-peek) I was expecting feedback for it to go on [meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com).  Instead we have been directed to post feedback here on [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

I thought that meta.stackoverflow.com was for StackOverflow material and that meta.stackexchange.com would be for the new StackExchange platform.

Why are we supposed to post StackExchange feedback here?

Comment: I still don't understand why meta.stackexchange and meta.stackoverflow aren't condensed into one site

Comment: @Earlz: Because there are degrees of freedom on stackexchange that aren't available on the SOFU sites?

Comment: @dmc I win! They are merging! lol

Comment: didn't Joel say that every SE site would have a meta site? So MSO and MSE will get merged, and then a new MSO site created?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We're in the process of consolidating the two "brands".  Stack Exchange is no longer a separate product: it's now the name for the entire network, of which Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User are the founding members.

Just today we merged http://blog.stackexchange.com and https://blog.stackoverflow.com so that we only have one blog for people to check.  Going forward we want to do the same thing to meta.SO and meta.SE but it's a little tricky since there's more content at meta.SE.

Basically, blog.SO and meta.SO are named wrong, because they've always been about the entire network, not just stackoverflow.com.  Since we can't change them without breaking existing links, we have to make both domains work.

Comment: But then stackoverflow doesn't have a meta.

Comment: I agree with Arlen's concern. This seems wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It would be nice if reputation points from Meta:SE carry over to this site once they're merged.  It doesn't matter much for my paltry numbers, but given the  frustration that any transision brings, it'd be one less annoyance for SE 1.0 embracers.  And one would think that the "credibility and trust" earned in that space is reasonably fungible to this one.

Comment: This is an interesting one. As one of the top users on meta.se, I'd like to see my rep preserved, on the other hand a lot (all?) of that reputation was earned from questions and answers which are no longer relevant, so would probably be purged in a migration.

Comment: poor jay... already addicted to the rep crack.

Comment: @perspicacity, I don't think I agree with you.  But I will reconsider if you vote up my answer.