# Does Meta Stack Exchange reputation count for a commitment in Area 51?

Tags: support, reputation, area-51, meta, commitment-phase

As far as I understood from an [old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52125/should-meta-stackexchange-reputation-be-counted-on-area-51) from 2010, the Meta reputation doesn't count for the "200+ reputation" criteria in the Commitment stage of a site proposal. Is it still in this way or did it change during these years?

Comment: Worth noting that the Meta Stack Exchange referred to in that post was a completely different site that has since been deleted from the Internet; it was the support site for the old Stack Exchange 1.0 sites (the old model where people would pay for public sites). Prior to April 2014, this site was known as Meta Stack Overflow, so any references to this site's current name before then refer to said old site.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation. So, at least, it should not be considered a duplicate. But still seems to not count

Answer (score 7):

This is still the case, it seems. I just committed a proposal with my sockpuppet, which has over 300 reputation on Meta Stack Exchange but no other accounts with 200 or more reputation. The number of committers increased by one, but the % complete for the 100 committers with 200 or more reputation did not increase, even after waiting a couple of hours for potential caching.

It's rather strange, since Meta Stack Exchange *does* appear on the network flairs in various places on Area 51.

Comment: But maybe the % complete is cached, I'll give it few more hours.

Comment: In case this is true, I'd take a guess and say the reason is MSE is marked as "meta site" internally and Area51 code just ignore sites with this mark, not checking if they also happen to have "main site" mark in place.

Comment: I find it wired too, but I'm new to SE, so not sure how it should be. But thank you for confirming @Glorfindel