# Can moderators from other sites be differentiated here?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page, meta, moderators

I am active mainly on Programmers now, but keep an eye out on meta and stackoverflow for questions about Programmers. Several times I have seen questions/answers from our moderators, but the only reason I know they are moderators is that I know. Can we have a way to tell what users are mods on other SE sites?

Perhaps a circle instead of a diamond would be good. I personally would like hovering over the symbol to show what site they moderate.

Comment: Makes sense.  ` `

Comment: This is a good idea, it'll keep me from being sarcastic, rude, and pedantic to people that would later ban me in another site...

Comment: Give me my diamond on every frigging SE-site already!

Comment: It would mean I wouldn't have to add "speaking as moderator on X" to the relevant posts

Comment: Sounds good to me - especially as so few folks appear to have heard of security.se, so have no idea where I have popped up from :-)

Comment: Is this intended only for MSO then?

Comment: @Michael That's my thought, yes. I don't think it's appropriate for other sites - since MSO covers issues across the network that could affect all moderators, it would be helpful to know right away that the person speaking is a mod somewhere. Also, several site mods are active here as well, and it show that their (hopefully :)) more knowledgable answers carry more weight.

Answer (score 45):

> Perhaps a circle instead of a diamond would be good.

Well - a white diamond with black outline

## ◊

might fit better to the known moderator icon, while circles are used in badges.

> I personally would like hovering over the symbol to show what site they moderate.

This would be nice, I agree.

Comment: You mean like that?

Comment: To any particular person who thinks the diamond looks like comic sans.. that's only because your browser's default font is set that way.  Also, get help.

Comment: @Won't: Yes, nearly exactly. But the size should be equal to the other size.

Answer (score 14):

> Several times I have seen questions/answers from our moderators, but the only reason I know they are moderators is that I know.

I'm not seeing how that's a problem.

Moderators do come and go. There are posts and comments here from folks who weren't moderators when they posted them, then were moderators somewhere, and now aren't anymore. Either the post has merit, offers up good information or suggests something useful... or it doesn't; the user's role elsewhere has no intrinsic value on that. On those rare occasions when it *matters*, it should be mentioned in the post itself!

Answer (score 12):

This sounds like a spot-on suggestion to this particular problem.

But I think it speaks to a bigger problem with MSO being uniquely dual-purpose in its use: it is the meta discussion for Stack Overflow, but it is also used for Q&A on cross-cutting/site-independent/Careers issue. <s>Perhaps it's time for a separate Meta Stack Exchange?</s>

<s>*wait, what?* The "meta" link on http://stackexchange.com points to MSO, but there actually is an [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), it's about the old [SE 1.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354).</s>

<s>https://meta.stackexchange.com/ now redirects to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/.</s>

https://meta.stackexchange.com/ is now a Meta site for questions that apply to the whole Stack Exchange network.

Comment: A separate MSE is in the works, but it'll be a little while. Can't remember the post where this was confirmed offhand though.

Comment: MSE is for SE 1.0 sites, but probably the people clicking "meta" on stackexchange.com are looking for this

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with its dual purpose...

Comment: @Pop, wow, sounds like the equivalent of a divorce. Could be traumatic for us meta-heads :)

Comment: Bleh, still can't find the one I was thinking of, but [this two-month-old post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72147/) is pretty close. It states that MSE will be eliminated soon/eventually, and _possibly_ become a redirect to MSO. Older posts: [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57265/) has Jeff's and Robert's points of view from July 2010; [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58159/) is from Jeff a few days later; and [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52026/) has David confirming the merge but is the oldest of them all.

Comment: Update on @PopularDemand's comment -- this did happen; http://meta.stackexchange.com/ leads here now

Comment: See my [later answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106456/131713) on this topic for slightly more info. Thanks for the poke, @MichaelMrozek.

Comment: After the split, this answer is very confusingly wrong/outdated...